# how to group list elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, list

Can somebody help me convert the following html

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

into this one

```
<ul>
  <li class="li_group">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="li_group">
    <ul>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul
```

using jQuery?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick...

```
var $liWrapper = $("<li class='li_group'><ul></ul></li>");
$("li").slice(0,2).wrapAll($liWrapper)
       .end()
       .slice(2,4).wrapAll($liWrapper);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you may end up needing to do this for a different number of items. My solution includes a while loop. Adjust the number in the while() condition, and in the selector for the :lt(2) to capture a different number of list items.

```
<ul id="divide">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
while ($('ul#divide > li[class!="li_group"]:lt(2)').length >= 1) {
    $('ul#divide > li[class!="li_group"]:lt(2)')
        .wrapAll('<li class="li_group"><ul></ul></li>');
}
</script>
```

While debugging I used this CSS to assure I was producing the right HTML.

```
<style type="text/css">
ul { border: 1px solid #f00; }
.li_group { border: 1px solid #00f; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

Jquery function :

```
jQuery.fn.groupListElement = function() {

    var $list = $(this[0]);
    var args = arguments[0] || {};
    var groupClassName = args.groupClassName || 'li_group';
    var size = args.size || 2;

    if ( $list.length > 0 ) {

        var wrapper = '<li class="' + groupClassName + '"><ul></ul></li>';

        while ( $('> li[class!="' + groupClassName + '"]',$list).slice(0, size).length >= 1) {
            $('> li[class!="' + groupClassName + '"]',$list).slice(0, size)
                .wrapAll(wrapper);
        }

    }

    return $list;

};
```

Call to the function

```
$('ul').groupListElement({groupClassName: 'li_group', size : 3});
```

Use with Jquery Cycle :

```
$('ul')
 .groupListElement({groupClassName: 'li_group', size : 3})
 .cycle();
```

Enjoy !